# Where is the log about Devise send confirmation email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I just config email settings and try to sign up a new account in my app.

It should send confirmation email but there is nothing happened and there is no error shown.

Where could I get logs to see if there is any problem in my configuration files?

The following is also my config in development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
:address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
:port                 => 587,
:domain               => 'mail.google.com',
:user_name            => 'account@gmail.com',
:password             => 'password',
:authentication       => 'plain',
:enable_starttls_auto => true  }
```

Edited,
newest config is as following:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'smtp.gmail.com:587' }

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
:address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
:port                 => 587,
:user_name            => "account@gmail.com",
:password             => "password",
:domain               => "gmail.com",
:authentication       => :login }
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify if you had configured the `default_url_options`

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'example.com' }
```

If you are testing in `development` and your log level is `debug`, action_mailer will display something like this in the log:

```
Sent mail to xxx@gmail.com

From: a@b.com
To: xxx@gmail.com
Subject: You have been registered with example.com
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

....blah blah blah...
```

EDIT: I see too many things changing between your two mail configurations. So, posting mine for reference

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'example.com' }
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port                 => 587,
      :user_name            => 'abc@gmail.com',
      :password             => 'password',
      :authentication       => 'plain',
      :enable_starttls_auto => true  }
```

Comment: Thanks. I can see what you say in development.log. There is no error but i  still haven't receive mail.

Comment: Cross-verify your configuration again. See EDIT. Also, check the sent mails folder in your gmail account to see if the mail is listed there..

Comment: Finally, solve it by the follow the link http://yekmer.posterous.com/devise-gmail-smtp-configuration
Thanks a lot!